# How to catch auto scale scaleUp event in another POD?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

Both server POD and client POD runs in a K8S cluster.
I have configured my Server POD to Scale up when its memory usage reaches a threshold.

Now I want to increase number of threads in my client POD whenever a new server POD is spawned.
How to catch this auto scale scaleUp event in the client POD ?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to increase number of threads in my client POD whenever a new server POD is spawned. How to catch this auto scale scaleUp event in the client POD ?

An application typically should not know that it is running within Kubernetes, e.g. it should be agnostic to this kind of information.

But it is fully possible to create an application (e.g. your client?) that know about the Kubernetes environment, and what happens in the environment. You need to interact with the APIServer to get this information, this is typically done by using [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) (if using Golang) but there is libraries for other languages as well, e.g. [Kubernetes Java client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java). You can e.g. watch for events or number of replicas for your server.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. Conceptually it should be the other way round: when your client puts more load then the server scales; or said differently when the client is scaled due to incoming requests, for example, then more load is put on the server causing the autoscaler to act.

Technically it is possible to watch for scale up events through K8s programming libraries for languages as @Jonas referred.

Comment: The product is legacy product and fixed number of threads connect to server using tcp sockets. There will be only one client. So even though Server is scaling up, since the client has fixed number of threads the scaled up server pod is not receiving any traffic and sitting idle.